# HttpClient - The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded

Tags: .net, httpclient

I use .Net Framework 4.6.1  [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.6.1) to call my .Net API 2 and received the error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded.

It's seem the `ETag` response header is too long. How can I increase the response header size limit? I searched and read multiple post/discussion talking about this bug, however it does not work.

Comment: why is the ETag so large?

Comment: We hash the response content for ETag

Comment: And how large is it?

Comment: About 6000 bytes because the response content is too large

Comment: The size of the hash should be constant and not effected by the size of the data. Use an established algorithm such as  SHA1.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I resolved the problem. The problem is in the hash function.